# Database lock in the program?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, locking

There is a database lock in the program, how can I fix it?

The inserting products bit works fine, it's just the categories bit that tells me the database is locked and doesn't work:

```
  import sqlite3
def insert_product(product):
    with sqlite3.connect("main.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = "insert into Products (CatID,Name,Qty,Price) values (?, ?, ?, ?)"
        cursor.execute(sql, product)
        db.commit()
        print("The product {0} has been inserted successfully" .format(Name))
        cursor = db.execute("SELECT ProductID, CatId, Name, Qty, Price from Products")
        for row in cursor:
            print ("ID = ", row[0])
            print ("CatID = ", row[1])
            print ("NAME = ", row[2])
            print ("Qty = ", row[3])
            print ("Price = ", row[4], "\n")


def insert_category(category):
    with sqlite3.connect("main.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = "insert into categories (Name) values (?)"
        cursor.execute(sql, category)
        db.commit()
        print("The category {0} has been inserted successfully" .format(Name))
        cursor = db.execute("SELECT CatID,Name from categories")
        for row in cursor:
            print ("CatID = ", row[0])
            print ("Name = ", row[1], "\n")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    response = input("Do you want to insert a category or a product (c/p) ?")
    if response == "p":
        ID= input("enter the CatID of the product:>> ")
        Name = input("Enter the name of the Product you want to insert: >>")
        Qty = input("Enter the quantity of the stock available: >>")
        Price = input("Enter the price of the product: >>")
        product = (ID,Name,Qty,Price)
        insert_product(product)
        print ("Product inserted successfully")
    else:
        Name = input("Enter the name of the Category you want to insert: >>")
        category = (Name,)
        insert_category(category)
        db.commit()
        print ("The new category {0} has been inserted successfully" .format(Name))
```

The problem that I am getting is:

```
cursor.execute(sql, category)

sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

Comment: Hi Saqib, does this happen only when you save insert product first and then try to insert the category? Or it happen also when you try to insert the category first? The CatID of Category is supposed to be autogenereated and saved in the db?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the ID is autogenerated but now it happens also when i insert a product. it just doesn't let me insert anything in the database tables using this code it says database is locked

Comment: Try to stop the run of your program. After that try to close the connection after the prints: db.close()

Comment: @PeterRing i dont know exactly what you mean is is possible if you can share some code.thanks

Comment: After you printed everything in "for row in cursor:" Close the connection to the DB with the command "db.close()"

Comment: @PeterRing still doesn't work

Comment: Hi @SaqibMalik can you show us how and where exactly you are closing the db connection?
I am sure there is very less chance of mistake but just to be sure.